# Change a custom field value after X number of seconds

Tags: custom-field

Is it possible to change the value of a custom field after X number of seconds has passed since it was modified?

For example, I have a checkbox that a user can check to say whether or not they are available. By default the box is unchecked and what I want to do is, 7200 seconds (2 hours) after a user has checked the box, revert it back to unchecked.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two meta fields: the 'available' field, and a 'lastchecked' field that contains a Unix timestamp for when the box was checked.

Then, you can use wp_cron (assuming your site has enough traffic; but most sites will get at least one visit an hour; if not, you can always set up a regular cron to visit your site every hour) to run your reset.

Assuming the meta fields are named as above, and 'available' is 1 for yes, 0 for no:

```
function reset_available_meta() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'lastchecked',
                'value'   =>  time() - ( 60 * 60 * 2 ), // 2 hours ago
                'compare' => '<='
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $resetQ = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $resetQ->have_posts() ) {
        $resetQ->the_post();
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'available', '0' );

        //optional: update lastchecked so it's not included for the next call
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'lastchecked', time() );
    }
}

wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'reset_available_meta' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this like an option you have saved to the database?
If so you could use [wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event).

At the same time you save the option that the user is available, push a scheduled event in two hours to revert the option back.

edit: Also when reverting the option back, remember to unschedule the event.

Alternatively, you could save a timestamp when saving the availability and when you check if the person is available, if the timestamp is over 2 hours old, change them not to be.